# Select rows from a DataFrame based on list values in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and I have a simple dataframe and want to extract certain rows based on a column. However, **the type in this column is a list**.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['text1', [1,2,3]], ['text2', [2,3,4]]], columns=['text','list_value'])
```

The data frame looks like:

```
    text    list_value
0   text1   [1, 2, 3]
1   text2   [2, 3, 4]
```

I tried

```
df.loc[df['list_value'] == [1,2,3]]
```

And it returns an error :

```
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 2 vs 3
```

I wonder if there is any better solution than using for loop to iterate the dataframe.

Similar question but the solution is not work for me: [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adding `apply` `tuple`, when there is list in a cell , pandas sometime return the wired result

```
df.loc[df['list_value'].apply(tuple) == tuple([1,2,3])]
Out[58]: 
    text list_value
0  text1  [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Great Thanks!  but i cannot understand why the error is `Arrays were different lengths: 2 vs 3`. I guess 3 is the length of the list in the column, but what is 2?