# Pandas: How to remove rows from a dataframe based on a list of tuples representing values in TWO columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tuples

This is very much related to [Select rows from a DataFrame based on list values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284375/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-list-values-in-a-column-in-pandas), where instead of looking for just ONE column, I want to look for matching tuples in two columns.

Reproducible example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 'a'], [1, 3, 'b'], [1, 3, 'c'], [1, 4, 'b'], [1, 2, 'c'], [1, 7, 'c']])
df.columns = ['id1', 'id2', 'name']

print(df)
```

Sample DataFrame

```
    id1  id2 name
0    1    2    a
1    1    3    b
2    1    3    b
3    1    4    b
4    1    2    c
5    1    7    c
```

I have a list of tuples!

```
badTuples = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 5)]
```

In the first element of the tuples, `(1, 2)`; `1` is used to refer to the value in`'id1'` column, and `2` is used to refer to the value in`'id2'` column.

I want to remove such rows, which have a matching `('id1', 'id2')` tuple elements! It is sometimes the case that in the list of tuples
there are pairs `(1, 5)` which ARE NOT PRESENT in the DataFrame! In my example, we have only `(1, 2), (1, 3) and (1, 4)` as `id1, id2` pairs in the DataFrame!

In the case, I want that pair `(1, 5)` to be skipped.

The output DataFrame should be:

```
    id1  id2 name
3    1    4    b
5    1    7    c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df[~pd.Series(list(zip(df['id1'], df['id2']))).isin(badTuples)]
```

Or:

```
df = df[~df[['id1','id2']].apply(tuple, 1).isin(badTuples)]

print(df)
   id1  id2 name
3    1    4    b
5    1    7    c
```

Comment: Give me a moment, will run it and let you know.

Comment: Thanks mate! Works.