# select rows in dataframe not in different dataframe with different shape arrays and where object is not iterable

Tags: python, dataframe, select, uuid

I'm trying to select rows in a dataframe that don't share a uniqueID with an interim dataframe but when I use the following 
`NotProcessed= FileListDF.loc[FileListDF['DocID'] != InterimDF.DocID.tolist()]` I get

> ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 255 vs 246

when I'm expecting a dataframe containing 9 rows that are in FileListDF but not in InterimDF

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284375/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-list-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) appears to have encountered a similar issue but the answer isn't clear and when I try it I get

> 'UUID' object is not iterable

I'm not sure if its connected to me using `uuid.uuid4()` to create the DocID in the 1st instance

**Sample Data**

```
FileListDF..to_json

<bound method NDFrame.to_json of     Class                                 DocID
0      CC  c2571c68-0705-4c87-a42b-0971a73fedf4
1      CC  ab317908-8720-47ce-a8f6-453169259e48
2      CC  2b3d1aee-b4f6-4278-9db2-c7b6819bd14f
3      CC  9d4b9084-f623-445c-86d9-0458d6fb4135
4      CC  afe9dbb5-38a2-4c4e-9640-b1da1d37b66f
5      CC  56fa7edb-5020-44e7-98bc-5b0878fbf9ac
6      CC  7c27bcb8-b381-465e-a6e9-edc38cf24e5a
7      CC  a56e6f13-bf05-474a-9930-5f0ebad33eba
8      CC  81c31d76-cec3-4f1c-8ec1-107ecc1169d4
9      CC  1f8acf61-0a08-4b42-8ad1-38eeebc85ff2
10     CC  d6a6704c-21c6-4dc5-b9bd-de9e67ee7970
11     CC  d63dde24-9a2b-410d-aa7d-6a854b646a12
12     CC  a80367f9-36af-45bd-878e-d19461a3d3df
13     CC  31f74aff-e8df-43bb-a7d4-314caea6de20
14     CC  99052ee4-2481-4c81-92dd-81b446e76c15
15     CC  3827d0b4-5d0a-490a-a561-bf631bae6492
16     CC  fdbde364-776d-4532-8aca-874144a85df8
17     CC  4dfa630f-20b0-4a9e-bcf0-cdd4f18bb215
18     CC  f5b16b14-a058-4f2d-8461-25e68b02c68b
19     CC  a9f23eee-5b44-4d4e-baf8-19b78b4e3508
20     CC  344bfb49-3b22-4e2a-b815-a9eb46cbed1b
21     CC  ade5b2c3-5962-4d6d-9252-4f670b127682
22     CC  43fa1fb2-3681-4372-ab5a-f12059b3741c
23     CC  77f19056-fef8-4353-9740-01afa5557f47
24     CC  1c7cfc8a-57c6-4ad3-bce7-63b006352ed1
25     CC  e6db5e3c-4b3e-4b27-9558-e7334032c9c0
26     CC  68adb3b6-dfeb-4645-8ed2-610ae896e8c4
27     CC  c0163ee2-9e34-4636-a734-051151c50f29
28     CC  7b7d8549-8697-4b19-a033-e0068f5aa4d7
29     CC  7a976925-57c5-4972-a9e6-278dd322f6b4
..    ...                                   ...
225    JA  cd3a901e-a077-472e-a100-f082f011cc72
226    JA  d462729a-e1bc-4502-abc1-8dbd2b21103d
227    JA  f5338d8d-13dc-4a03-b720-1056419deb68
228    JA  37a41e22-3698-459d-b3cd-0d419a0f3f48
229    JA  e48c4463-565d-4f09-9ccc-03e0506ddf1e
230    JA  8531a863-4b0b-4bfa-9c4a-05056e7c1165
231    JA  01e72b43-730d-42a7-9405-6fd45b2141b5
232    JA  5ebbf1d4-48f1-4d1f-a5bc-1e865c92146f
233    JA  c3103348-2209-42de-8005-06a9af3ca43f
234    JA  b603b2cd-c4c9-4a2e-a52f-361a1e06b277
235    JA  32bf7eba-7425-4f9c-ad1f-95680c8ad7cc
236    JA  514f667e-5ba8-40fa-8c6f-bbf06bb6ff2f
237    JA  d08b06d1-b8fc-432b-94af-a25d9ef8b4fe
238    JA  d32419e8-e327-470b-95ba-1a2e20cff6d7
239    NA  abdd46ff-3b81-4b5e-85a1-95db783ff2fa
240    NA  3587088d-a592-4f21-93fe-760e9276fbd9
241    NA  8eb7ae93-ab3a-4e3c-ad42-129949dd0545
242    NA  8ff017c0-aae2-43e8-b87b-2889b9bb0df8
243    NA  1ad7c9d6-8da4-46e8-97ee-c0a6c3299d27
244    NA  fa5e928f-a906-480f-824c-4615a155cc2a
245    NA  1d1b709d-3472-4bd1-961b-453368b6845a
246    NA  e302d87f-30d7-46aa-9358-5705a31cf31b
247    NA  ad1043ba-5807-482b-a4a0-624bbfbd36af
248    NA  94c4453f-1309-4931-9a8f-5400a1b104f5
249    NA  37aca929-a2fd-4055-a416-865b92ebe58c
250    NA  ad64522f-054a-4fcc-b1c2-fbf70eb06a62
251    NA  c30a75f1-c144-4d62-a3bb-9f41615b9ca0
252    NA  559c0a5e-7e76-4e4f-a560-1c4d52b31384
253    NA  5a123bb7-9ffb-46b2-b315-6e2f0aca7aed
254    NA  595da36e-ec30-40e4-abc1-b98400ae9303
```

This is the dataframe of DocIDs that I want to remove matching values from FileListDF above to find the same number of rows that are in FileListDF but not in InterimDF

```
InterimDF.to_json

<bound method NDFrame.to_json of                                     DocID
0    c2571c68-0705-4c87-a42b-0971a73fedf4
1    ab317908-8720-47ce-a8f6-453169259e48
2    2b3d1aee-b4f6-4278-9db2-c7b6819bd14f
3    9d4b9084-f623-445c-86d9-0458d6fb4135
4    56fa7edb-5020-44e7-98bc-5b0878fbf9ac
5    7c27bcb8-b381-465e-a6e9-edc38cf24e5a
6    a56e6f13-bf05-474a-9930-5f0ebad33eba
7    81c31d76-cec3-4f1c-8ec1-107ecc1169d4
8    1f8acf61-0a08-4b42-8ad1-38eeebc85ff2
9    d6a6704c-21c6-4dc5-b9bd-de9e67ee7970
10   d63dde24-9a2b-410d-aa7d-6a854b646a12
11   a80367f9-36af-45bd-878e-d19461a3d3df
12   31f74aff-e8df-43bb-a7d4-314caea6de20
13   99052ee4-2481-4c81-92dd-81b446e76c15
14   3827d0b4-5d0a-490a-a561-bf631bae6492
15   fdbde364-776d-4532-8aca-874144a85df8
16   4dfa630f-20b0-4a9e-bcf0-cdd4f18bb215
17   f5b16b14-a058-4f2d-8461-25e68b02c68b
18   a9f23eee-5b44-4d4e-baf8-19b78b4e3508
19   344bfb49-3b22-4e2a-b815-a9eb46cbed1b
20   ade5b2c3-5962-4d6d-9252-4f670b127682
21   43fa1fb2-3681-4372-ab5a-f12059b3741c
22   77f19056-fef8-4353-9740-01afa5557f47
23   1c7cfc8a-57c6-4ad3-bce7-63b006352ed1
24   e6db5e3c-4b3e-4b27-9558-e7334032c9c0
25   68adb3b6-dfeb-4645-8ed2-610ae896e8c4
26   c0163ee2-9e34-4636-a734-051151c50f29
27   7b7d8549-8697-4b19-a033-e0068f5aa4d7
28   7a976925-57c5-4972-a9e6-278dd322f6b4
29   6533a84b-a81d-411a-b44e-3090cd01396d
..                                    ...
216  f7217b94-b939-4bcf-b8c8-d385e4473c63
217  74522cf3-7fd5-4b84-b175-23f84ede25ae
218  cd3a901e-a077-472e-a100-f082f011cc72
219  d462729a-e1bc-4502-abc1-8dbd2b21103d
220  f5338d8d-13dc-4a03-b720-1056419deb68
221  37a41e22-3698-459d-b3cd-0d419a0f3f48
222  e48c4463-565d-4f09-9ccc-03e0506ddf1e
223  8531a863-4b0b-4bfa-9c4a-05056e7c1165
224  01e72b43-730d-42a7-9405-6fd45b2141b5
225  5ebbf1d4-48f1-4d1f-a5bc-1e865c92146f
226  c3103348-2209-42de-8005-06a9af3ca43f
227  b603b2cd-c4c9-4a2e-a52f-361a1e06b277
228  d08b06d1-b8fc-432b-94af-a25d9ef8b4fe
229  d32419e8-e327-470b-95ba-1a2e20cff6d7
230  abdd46ff-3b81-4b5e-85a1-95db783ff2fa
231  3587088d-a592-4f21-93fe-760e9276fbd9
232  8eb7ae93-ab3a-4e3c-ad42-129949dd0545
233  8ff017c0-aae2-43e8-b87b-2889b9bb0df8
234  1ad7c9d6-8da4-46e8-97ee-c0a6c3299d27
235  fa5e928f-a906-480f-824c-4615a155cc2a
236  1d1b709d-3472-4bd1-961b-453368b6845a
237  e302d87f-30d7-46aa-9358-5705a31cf31b
238  ad1043ba-5807-482b-a4a0-624bbfbd36af
239  94c4453f-1309-4931-9a8f-5400a1b104f5
240  37aca929-a2fd-4055-a416-865b92ebe58c
241  ad64522f-054a-4fcc-b1c2-fbf70eb06a62
242  c30a75f1-c144-4d62-a3bb-9f41615b9ca0
243  559c0a5e-7e76-4e4f-a560-1c4d52b31384
244  5a123bb7-9ffb-46b2-b315-6e2f0aca7aed
245  595da36e-ec30-40e4-abc1-b98400ae9303
```

Comment: Please include a small sample of each dataframe.

Comment: Exported 2 dataframes as json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you have two dataframes that each have a column with some overlap between the two.

For simplicity, I'm going to call them `df_one` and `df_two` and they both have an `id` column.

You can use `isin()` to filter down to just the overlap, or the converse to filter those out.

eg

```
import pandas as pd

df_one = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df_two = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[3,4,5,6,7]})

new_ids = ~df_one['id'].isin(df_two['id'])

df_only_in_one = df_one[new_ids]
```

Comment: A bit but df_two doesn't have the same number of rows as df_two and when I try the above I get a dataframe with 255 rows. I only want the 9 rows that are in df_one but not in df_two

Comment: the row count does not matter, the dataframes need not match.  The fourth line of my example is effectively iterating through one array (`df_one['id']`) and for each element checking it against the entirety of the second array (`df_two['id']`).  It might help if you explicitly converted your dataframe column into an array.

Comment: Hands up I had the order incorrect of my dataframes in my code so was always going to find all the ids and only get a result of True. I also had to run .fillna in place to replace NaN with False but finally ended up with a column in the dataframe 1 I could filter to show the unique Ids that did not found in dataframe 2